# Google G Suite ( Workspace ) How to disable the passcode on the device

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-admin-sdk, google-workspace

Our team uses Google Calendar to share the schedule, and it works fine by using the browser. But when we use the app on the phone (both iOS and Android), it will always show a warning message like:

`Your org requires you to set a passcode on this device to access this account. Please set a passcode and try again.`

How can I disable this message from the admin console of Google G Suite (Workspace)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is now (as of May 2022) found under the
`Devices > Mobile and endpoints > Universal Settings > General`  
section of the Google Admin page for the organization.

To disable it you should select "Turn off mobile management (Unmanaged)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To disable that perk you need to open your Admin console (I assume that you have administrative privileges) and search the following highlighted option. You could find it by searching the keywords *Require users to set a password*.

[image: Password requirements]

Open that option and look for the *Require users to set a password* checkbox and unmark it. Then just save and wait for the changes to propage. Please, ask me any additional questions for this answer.